# How to vertically align a span and text in an HTML paragraph?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a clickable rounded rectangle that will change color when clicked, using bootstrap. The best way I found to do this is with a span.

Here is the example code I've written:

```
<p id="proyect_c_leasons" style="height:30px;vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell"> <span class="label label-default" style="background-color:#D80909;width:35px;height:25px;display:inline-block" onclick='console.log("hola")'>  </span> <b>Lecciones Aprendidas</b> </p>
```

This is what it shows:

[image]

What I want is the text to be align to the middle of the red square instead of the bottom of the red square.

This code:

```
<p id="proyect_c_leasons"> <span class="label label-default" style="background-color:#D80909;width:35px;height:25px;display:inline-block" onclick='console.log("hola")'>  </span> <b>Lecciones Aprendidas</b> </p>
```

Shows the exact same thing (basically p ignores everything I write into style)

Can anyone provide me with a way to fix this? Or an alternative?

Comment: Simulating a `table` with CSS. Tables cells are vertically centered by default or it can be modified by using `vertical-align`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set line-height for the div and then vertical-align the span within.

```html
<p id="proyect_c_leasons" style="height:30px;line-height:30px;display:table-cell"> 
  <span class="label label-default" style="background-color:#D80909;width:35px;height:30px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" onclick='console.log("hola")'>  
  </span>  
  <b>Lecciones Aprendidas</b> 
</p>
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/BdUXdItlMO)

Comment: This does what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `vertical-align: middle;` and `line-height` equal to the `height` to the `<span>`:

```html
<p id="proyect_c_leasons">
  <span class="label label-default" style="background-color:#D80909;width:35px;height:25px;line-height:25px;display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;" onclick='console.log("hola")'></span>
  <b>Lecciones Aprendidas</b>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <p id="proyect_c_leasons" style="line-height: 25px;"> <span class="label label-default" style="background-color:#D80909;width:35px;height:25px;display:inline-block; float: left;" onclick='console.log("hola")'>  </span> <b>Lecciones Aprendidas</b> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was somewhat unclear what you were asking here, so I'll answer both interpretations.

**a) You want the text in the middle of the square (contained within)**

This is a relatively simple change. You just need to contain the text within the span.

**b) You want the text to be vertically in the middle of the square (still outside of it)**

For this, you'll want to look at text alignment.

```
<p id="proyect_c_leasons" style="height:30px;vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell">
<span class="label label-default" style="background-color:#D80909;width:35px;height:25px;display:inline-block" onclick='console.log("hola")'>
</span>
<b style="vertical-align: 40%;">Lecciones Aprendidas</b>
```

In the example above I've literally only changed the style for the `<b>` tag. You can alter where it lies by changing the percentage. There are a variety of different options available to you, which are listed on mdn:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align